# Loading all symbols of a particular type in a package

Tags: go, reflection

I would like to load all symbols of a type from a golang testing package.

What I would like to accomplish is something like [pytest's fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), where I define an interface

```
type Fixture func(...Fixture) interface{}
var MyFixture = func() interface{} {
        return 1}
```

and then to use reflection on the package to load all fixtures and inject them into the test using the test runner.

(I know the reflect package won't give me the parameter names, thats a separate problem i need to solve).

I have two issues, reading [Go (reflect): How to discover all package types at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132064/go-reflect-how-to-discover-all-package-types-at-runtime), I tried to use the `Default()` importer, but I always get a panic:

```
pkg, err := importer.Default().Import("fmt")
// error was nil
// pkg is nil
```

randomly prints the following string from somewhere `can't find import:`

Comment: What Go version are you using? In what environment are you running your code? For me using the `Detault()` importer works just fine.

Comment: I'm using Linux, go version 1.8