# Get all info about a package via importer and reflect?

Tags: go, go-reflect

I stumbled across this answer to a question on how to get all the types in a package:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32142080/470339

Which works great. However, the next step I'd like to take is then iterate over each of these types to get, for example, `NumMethod()`. I don't see an immediately obvious way to do so - can anyone shed some light, or will I have to resort to messing with the AST?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Scope` and the names to [Lookup](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Scope.Lookup) the `Object`s you're interested in.

> An Object describes a named language entity such as a package,
>   constant, type, variable, function (incl. methods), or label. All
>   objects implement the Object interface.

There is a [Named](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Named) type that implements the `Object` interface and that has a method called `NumMethods`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/importer"
    "go/types"
)

func main() {
    pkg, err := importer.Default().Import("time")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    }

    scope := pkg.Scope()
    for _, name := range scope.Names() {
        if name == "Time" {
            obj := scope.Lookup(name)
            if tn, ok := obj.Type().(*types.Named); ok {
                fmt.Printf("%#v\n", tn.NumMethods())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Then, if you want to go further, `*types.Named` implements the [Type](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Type) interface, so you can look at its underlying type which is also a `types.Type` implemented by [Struct](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Struct), [Slice](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#Slice), etc.