# Creating empty Kubernetes resource struct when knowing the resource kind/type only (in golang)

Tags: go, kubernetes

How can I create an empty struct of a certain Kubernetes resource when the resource kind/type is given as string ?

I.e.

```golang
var object *runtime.Object

object = factory.NewResourceFromKind("pod")
```

and `object` should then contain `&apiv1.Pod{}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing the `Kind` is not enough, however a combination of API Group + API Version + object Kind ([`GroupVersionKind`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema#GroupVersionKind)) would allow you to use the information contained in the default [`scheme.Scheme`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme#pkg-variables) variable to generate a new object.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme"
)

func main() {
    // apiVersion's syntax is "group/version" for non-core API groups
    // e.g. "apps/v1"
    podGvk := schema.FromAPIVersionAndKind("v1", "Pod")

    obj, err := scheme.Scheme.New(podGvk)  // error handling omitted

    fmt.Printf("%T", obj)
    /* prints '*v1.Pod' */
}
```

See godoc for [`func (*Scheme) New`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime#Scheme.New)

Answer (score 1):

There is no pretty way to do this.

This would require two steps:

1. Building a type map: map[string]reflect.Type

You could either write your own code to go through each k8s api type and insert into a map, as in this answer: [is there a way to create an instance of a struct from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030884/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-struct-from-a-string)

Or, you could use an extremely non-portable method to extract types from binaries, which allows you to avoid knowing which types to add to the map:
[How to discover all package types at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132064/how-to-discover-all-package-types-at-runtime)

2. Use the map to instantiate.  Lookup myType from a string using the map, then:

   reflect.New(myType).Elem()

where myType is the instance of reflect.Type