# How can i get all struct under a package in Golang?

Tags: go

Can we list all struct in the form of name or interface, under a package?
Like:

```
struct := list("fmt")
```

expected result:

```
Formatter
GoStringer
Scanner
State
Stringer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all defined struct in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803758/how-to-get-all-defined-struct-in-golang)

Comment: Go doesn't provide this kind of reflection. You cannot make assumptions about symbol names and generally stuff that you don't actually use.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is parse the [go sources](http://golang.org/src/) (which [you can clone](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/checkout): `hg clone https://code.google.com/p/go/`), and isolate the [`ast.StructType`](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#StructType).

That is what a [pretty printer does](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/usr/gri/pretty/printer.go?spec=svn85a7fd8668385a9d259207def8ac99bb2bbf2906&r=85a7fd8668385a9d259207def8ac99bb2bbf2906#482):

```
func (P *Printer) Type(t *AST.Type) int {
    separator := semicolon;

    switch t.form {

    case AST.STRUCT, AST.INTERFACE:
            switch t.form {
            case AST.STRUCT: P.String(t.pos, "struct");
            case AST.INTERFACE: P.String(t.pos, "interface");
            }
            if t.list != nil {
                    P.separator = blank;
                    P.Fields(t.list, t.end);
            }
            separator = none;
```

In the same idea, the [linter go/lint](https://github.com/golang/lint) does the same [in lint.go](https://github.com/golang/lint/blob/115818a90fadbec0684a025f6b8e586257501639/lint.go#L375-L381):

```
    case *ast.StructType:
        for _, f := range v.Fields.List {
            for _, id := range f.Names {
                check(id, "struct field")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Like this way, but seems really dirty and unofficial.

Comment: @AnthonyTsang no, the linter uses the official way to list structures. This isn't "dirty", this is a consequence of how the language is done, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22222911/6309.

Comment: maybe I should expand more my use case. I am from PHP which is so dynamic that allows me to do almost anything. So I was wounding if I can do it in Golang. I want to list all structs under a package and init them and use them. My use case exactly is "What looks easy at the beginning will end up in debugging and maintenance nightmare". Therefore, I need to stop here and design again.